# MariaDB cursor loop issue

Tags: mysql, loops, cursor, mariadb

My cursor is just processing 1st record and coming out. it's not going to second record. what could be the issue? Below is my code:

There are more than 600,000 rows to process. When I execute the select query it shows me a correct number of rows but the loop is not working.

```
Delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE  p_updateHistory_1()
BEGIN
DECLARE v_symbol varchar(10);
DECLARE v_pricedate date;

DECLARE done BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT symbol, PriceDate 
           from StockData
           where PriceDate > '2016-06-30'
           order by symbol asc, PriceDate desc;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN cur1;

read_loop: LOOP
FETCH cur1 INTO v_symbol, v_pricedate;

If done THEN
    LEAVE read_loop;
END IF;

Update StockData SET
20DayTPAvg = f_TP20avg(symbol,PriceDate),
20DayMFSum = f_20DayMFSum(symbol,PriceDate),
20DayVolumeSum = f_20DayVolumeSum(symbol,PriceDate),
MFFactor = f_20DayMFSum(symbol,PriceDate)/f_20DayVolumeSum(symbol,PriceDate),
50DayHighestHigh = f_50DayHighestHigh(symbol,PriceDate),
50DayLowestLow = f_50DayLowestLow(symbol,PriceDate),
50DayFactor = ((close-f_50DayLowestLow(symbol,PriceDate))/(f_50DayHighestHigh(symbol,PriceDate)-f_50DayLowestLow(symbol,PriceDate)))*100,
20DayAvgOf50DayFactor = f_20DayAvgOf50DayFactor(symbol,PriceDate),
50DayMAvg20DayBfr = f_20DayMAvg20DayBfr(symbol,PriceDate),
20DayAvgSqCh50DMA = f_20DayAvgSqCh50DMA(symbol,PriceDate),
20dStdDevOf50DayMovAvg = SQRT(f_20DayAvgSqCh50DMA(symbol,PriceDate)),
UpperBand =  50DayMovingAvg+2*SQRT(f_20DayAvgSqCh50DMA(symbol,PriceDate)), 
LowerBand = 50DayMovingAvg-2*SQRT(f_20DayAvgSqCh50DMA(symbol,PriceDate)),
MidPointFactor = ((close-MidPoint)/(high-close))*100,
20DayAvgOfMPFactor = f_20DayAvgOfMPFactor(symbol,PriceDate)
Where symbol=v_symbol
And PriceDate=v_pricedate;

commit;

END LOOP;

CLOSE Cur1;

END $$
Delimiter ;
```

Comment: Any suggestions, if I am doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
According to MariaDB doc, if any select statement returns no data, the it will consider as "Not Found" and according to handler Done becomes true, hence stop fetching cursor.
Seems you are using many functions. Do check if any of the function return empty result.

Answer (score -3):

`CURSORs` are usually a mistake.  Can't you simply do this *one* statement, no cursor?

```
UPDATE StockData
    SET ...
    WHERE PriceDate > '2016-06-30';
```

Is `f_20DayAvgOf50DayFactor` (etc) a UDF or a Stored Function?

**Composite INDEX needed**

```
INDEX(symbol, PriceDate)
```

Comment: Though this answer is perhaps an alternate approach, it is not even remotely an answer to the question.